# My mother(who is a kafir) forbid me to fast in Ramadan

Tags: sawm, parents, conversion

I’m a 14 year old girl and i converted to Islam 8 months ago. Two weeks ago my mother finally found out. She told me to not pray anymore but of course I didn’t listen. I’ve been able to keep my fast for Ramadan until now. When she asks me if I’ve eaten I find a way to dodge that question, so I dont lie. But I suppose she’s been researching things about Islam because today was different. She asked me specifically if there was something that I was doing secretly like not eating during the day. I said no but she still told me not to do it because it’s really bad for my health. And tomorrow she wants me to go after school (around 2:30pm) to her work and wants us to eat together. I’ve been postponing this since the start of Ramadan but she is getting really suspicious.

So am I to be blamed if I break my sawm or if I lie to her as to keep it.

Comment: Did your mother ask you if you have eaten, or if you have *eaten by daylight*?